Natural language query to Elasticsearch query conversion
I have been working on a POC to build a Python code that converts natural language query to elasticsearch query DSL using an open-source LLM model.
I tried with text generation models like facebook/bart-large, gpt2 but didn't get the desired result. But when I use the same prompt in ChatGPT or Gemini, it provides the expected response.
Is there any open-source LLM I can use that would be the best fit for this solution?
Kind regards,
Souvik
